# images not showing on like box

Tags: photos, facebook-likebox

every day we post a photo album on our facebook page. They always used to show up in our like box embedded on our website until a couple of days ago. Now there is just a hyperlink to the album and nothing else. If we go back a month on our like box, we start to see photos again. What is causing this? does anyone know?

Comment: I have just discovered that by reducing the photo to a very small size, things start to work again. its not ideal but is a temporary solution until Facebook sort out the problem (from the forums i gather that the problem is at their end..)

Answer (score 0):

Use following meta tag to add image with like button:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="imageurl"/>
```

Comment: How can this meta-tag work with an embeded iframe like box generated from the facebook plugin? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
I can't be expected to upload an image from my smartphone to my facebook wall, then grab the url of that image and add it to a meta tag on my website just to get the image to display on my site!